# Disable active events

Tags: civievent

Is there a setting/scheduled job/something else, that can automatically set events in the state of inactive automatically after the event has ended?

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to resolve?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion we have a setup with displaying events on our website through a proxy setup, that means no direct use of native CiviEvent functionality. This setup checks for the state of the event. If the state is disabled, it will no konger be displayed, using the same logic as for relationships that gets automatically disabled after a scheduled job

Answer (score 1):

I am not if there is any but it's an easy one to develop via an extension or MySQL event or running MySQL via cron job.

**MySQL query via cron job**

using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196613/run-a-mysql-query-as-a-cron-job

```
UPDATE civicrm_event 
SET is_active = 0
WHERE end_date IS NOT NULL
  AND  DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 2 DAY) < now()
  AND is_active = 1;
```

**Mysql Event that will run everyday at 1:00 am**

```
CREATE EVENT disable_civicrm_events
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
  DO
  UPDATE civicrm_event 
  SET is_active = 0
  WHERE end_date IS NOT NULL
    AND  DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 2 DAY) < now()
    AND is_active = 1;
```